# Combining natural mode and boolean mode (Mysql Fulltext)

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search

I am trying to build a small search engine using mysql, not sure which is the best and hopefully simple way to do it. Reading some articles I suppose I should use the fulltext option in mysql and not some `like` stuff.
I found some disadvantages in using the natural mode as well as in using the boolean mode. Think it's interesting for the user to use things like `Zuckerberg -Facebook` which would be sth like this:

```
SELECT id,link,title,description,
match(title,description) 
against ('+Zuckerberg -Facebook' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as relevance
FROM Links
WHERE match(title,description) 
against ('+Zuckerberg -Facebook' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

but the relevance would always be 1 for boolean mode. 
On the other hand the `natural mode` doesn't allow `+ or -` as operators.
And it has a restriction with it's 50% threshold :/
Both `natural mode` and `boolean mode` have this minimum word length restriction which is a little bit annoying for abbreviations.
(I know that it's possible to change the minimum length but it's not possible without having a bit more server access)

I think that it might be possible to use the mysql `like` function for abbreviations but is there any way to order by relevance in the boolean mode?

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: The power of Google's search is immensely more than what little you can get out of `FULLTEXT`.  Tone down your expectations, or plan do write a _lot_ of code.  Also, check Solr and other plugins to see if they do more of what you want.

Comment: I have a new idea using `Natural Mode`